# InterruptedException in Producer/Consumer Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, java-threads

I have a Producer/Consumer Application , where i am reading from a JMS queue and passing the message to multiple consumer threads for processing.I am using blocking Queue for the same

How should i handle Interrupted exception in either case?

Comment: Please post your code with exact problem area

Comment: If you're the author of the application, then it's supposed to be up to you to define what an interrupt means.  But if it means anything other than "shut the application down," you're taking a risk that if the interrupt happens within some library call, it might not leave the library in a good state. If you're writing a _library_ then you should respond to an interrupt by aborting the current operation, maybe re-throwing the exception, and in any case, leave everything in a good state where the client can continue to use your library if it wishes.